# How remove/clear markers in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet

I must clear marker from map. I must implement function, which clear marker from id.

I'am using leaflet to implement map

My function

```js
public clearMarkers(): void {
    for (var id in this.markers) {
        //this.markers[id] and what i will do now?
    }
    this.markers = {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance of the map, you can use the [Map.removeLayer](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-removelayer) method to remove the marker, so your code would look something like:

```
// assuming the leaflet map is stored on an class variable 'map'
public clearMarkers(): void {
    for (var id in this.markers) {
        this.map.removeLayer(this.markers[id]);
    }
    this.markers = {}
}
```

where `this.map` is the reference to your leaflet map.

Comment: doesnt work i dont know why
i add marker to cluster like that
```this.mapPromise.then(map => {

            
                var mapMarkers = markers.map(marker => {
                    let newMarker = this.createMarker(marker)

                        clus.addLayer(newMarker)


                })

                 if (this.$scope.options.isClustering) {
                        this.mapCluster =  this.map.addLayer(clus)
                }```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `markercluster`, you need to clear the markers from the cluster layer.

`clus.clearLayers()` will remove all the markers.

Comment: i call the method when a change a page with data. I implement markercluster and where i must add `clearLayers` before declatration cluster?

Comment: Sorry, I can't imagine your code. Can you post relevant parts?